# Regular expression to validate textbox length

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want a regular expression to validate an ASP textbox field with the minimum length of 11 characters and in the middle of the string should be a "-" sign. The sample string is: "0000-011111". I want to validate the textbox to make sure user enters a minimum of 10 numbers with "-" sign after 4 digits using regular expressions. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You wrote that the minimum length should be 11, what's the maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\d{4}-\d{6}
```

`\d` represents a digit, `-` is a literal dash and the number in the curly brackets force the preceeding token to be present the given number of times.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{4}-\d{6,}$
```

You should use also `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end to ensure that there is nothing before and after your string that you don't want to have. Also important is the `{6,}` so it will match at least 6 digits, without `,` it will match exactly 6 digits. If you want set a maximum of digits you can specify after the `,`, e.g. `{6,20}`.